# How to add more than one link in Django 1.6.1 urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls

I am trying to add more than one link to my urls.py. First code below is in the app url, and other one in the main urls. However; when I am trying to add REGISTER and run the server, it still displays me the same of BLOG page.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
url(r'^register/', include('blog.urls')),

url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),)
```

This one in the main urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from blog import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
url(r'^$', views.register, name='register'),)
```

What should I do to fix this situation? Any idea will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main urls.py should have:

```
url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),)
```

and you should remove the register from app urls.

This will make yourapp.com/register/ point to views.register (or possibly yourapp.com/blog/register/ view it - I'm slightly confused on which urls.py is taking precedence)

Comment: Thanks for your urgent reply; however, it did not solve the problem. It is still same. When I access the 127.0.0.1:8000/register, it displays the same page of 127.0.0.1:8000/blog

Answer (score -1):

The first block of code should be in your project's folder/project folder/urls.py, so paste it there. The second block is perfect, it should be placed in the new urls.py that you have created recently in the apps folder.